# Which http code should return when there is no data

Tags: java, rest, web-services, http, jax-rs

I have written Rest API which return 200 http code when there is data in backend system.however which http status code i should return when there no data in backend system so that it will help client code to interpret response without any ambiguity.

Comment: HTTP 204 - No Content or 404 - Not Found

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have written Rest API which return 200 http code when there is data in backend system.however which http status code i should return when there no data in backend system so that it will help client code to interpret response without any ambiguity.

Quick review; the [status-code](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.2) describes...

> the result of the server's attempt to understand and satisfy the client's corresponding request.  The rest of the response message is to be interpreted in light of the semantics defined for that status code.

In other words, it's a shorthand classification of the *response*, not the state of the backend system.

> which http status code i should return when there no data in backend system so that it will help client code to interpret response without any ambiguity.

It depends on what "no data in backend system" means for your context.

If no data in the backend system indicates an error by the client, then you should be returning a status-code from the [Client Error 4xx](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5) class.

If no data in the backend system indicates an error by the server, then you should be returning a status-code from the [Server Error 5xx](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6) class.

If there have been no errors in the system at all (the request is good, the server is handling the request correctly), then you should be returning a status-code from the [Successful 2xx](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3) class

[204 No Content](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.5) has a precise meaning; it advises the client (and intermediary components) that the origin server's response includes no content in the response payload body.

> A 204 response is terminated by the first empty line after the header fields because it cannot contain a message body.

In other words, if your representation of no data available is an empty application/json object

```
{}
```

or an empty application/json array

```
[]
```

or an application/json null

```
null
```

and you are sending that representation to the client, then using the `204` status-code is *not* compliant with RFC 7321.  200 is almost certain to be the correct code to use in these cases.

Answer (score 3):

HTTP code 204 is used to say the request was successful and there's nothing to return. If there's no data found and that's believed to be an error, there's the classic 404. 
[HTTP status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)